# Limit number of records that can be written to a path (reference other paths in security rules)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security

Let's say my Firebase collection looks like:

```
{
  "max":5
  "things":{}
}
```

How would I use the value of `max` in my security rules to limit the number of `things`?

```
{
  "rules": {
    "things": {
      ".validate": "newData.val().length <= max"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using existing properties is done using [root](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/rule-expressions/root.html) or [parent](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/rulesdatasnapshot/parent.html) and is pretty straightforward.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "things": {
      // assuming value is being stored as an integer
      ".validate": "newData.val() <= root.child('max')"
    }
  }
}
```

However, determining the number of records and enforcing this is a bit more complex than simply writing a security rule:

- since there is no `.length` on an object, we need to store how many records exist
- we need to update that number in a secure/real-time way
- we need to know the number of the record we are adding relative to that counter

**A Naive Approach**

One poor-man's approach, assuming the limit is something small (e.g. 5 records), would be to simply enumerate them in the security rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "things": {
      ".write": "newData.hasChildren()", // is an object
      "thing1": { ".validate": true },
      "thing2": { ".validate": true },
      "thing3": { ".validate": true },
      "thing4": { ".validate": true },
      "thing5": { ".validate": true },
      "$other": { ".validate": false
    }
  }
}
```

**A Real Example**

A data structure like this works:

```
/max/<number>
/things_counter/<number>
/things/$record_id/{...data...}
```

Thus, each time a record is added, the counter must be incremented.

```
var fb = new Firebase(URL);
fb.child('thing_counter').transaction(function(curr) {
   // security rules will fail this if it exceeds max
   // we could also compare to max here and return undefined to cancel the trxn
   return (curr||0)+1;
}, function(err, success, snap) {
   // if the counter updates successfully, then write the record
   if( err ) { throw err; }
   else if( success ) {
      var ref = fb.child('things').push({hello: 'world'}, function(err) {
         if( err ) { throw err; }
         console.log('created '+ref.name());
      });
   }
});
```

And each time a record is removed, the counter must be decremented.

```
var recordId = 'thing123';
var fb = new Firebase(URL);
fb.child('thing_counter').transaction(function(curr) {
   if( curr === 0 ) { return undefined; } // cancel if no records exist
   return (curr||0)-1;
}, function(err, success, snap) {
   // if the counter updates successfully, then write the record
   if( err ) { throw err; }
   else if( success ) {
      var ref = fb.child('things/'+recordId).remove(function(err) {
         if( err ) { throw err; }
         console.log('removed '+recordId);
      });
   }
});
```

Now on to the security rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "max": { ".write": false },

    "thing_counter": {
      ".write": "newData.exists()", // no deletes
      ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() >= 0 && newData.val() <= root.child('max').val()"
    },

    "things": {
      ".write": "root.child('thing_counter').val() < root.child('max').val()"
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this doesn't force a user to write to thing_counter before updating a record, so while suitable for limiting the number of records, it's not suitable for enforcing game rules or preventing cheats.

**Other Resources and Thoughts**

If you want game level security, check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/B78Ce/), which details how to create records with incremental ids, including security rules needed to enforce a counter. You could combine that with the rules above to enforce a max on the incremental ids and ensure the counter is updated before the record is written.

Also, make sure you're not over-thinking this and there is a legitimate use case for limiting the number of records, rather than just to satisfy a healthy dose of worry. This is a lot of complexity to simply enforce a poor man's quota on your data structures.

Comment: This was very thorough - thank you for taking the time to walk me through this. Very helpful. Quick question on `$id >= 'rec'+root.child('incid/counter').val()` where `$id` is equal to the `counter` value found in your fiddle. If a user deletes an `$id` say record `3` we may be left with `1,2,4,5` at which point those rules would fall through right? How would I deal with this?

Comment: Hi Dan, yes those are two different strategies, one is for creating unique incremental records, the other is for enforcing a max. It would take a bit of scheming to combine the two, which I didn't do here.

Comment: I'm trying to imagine how it would be even possible to enforce both if `$id` wasn't an integer that matches the current `counter` value. What if the `.write` is on an object property that muiltiple records share or if every `$id` was random? Do you have any ideas that don't require `$id` to increment with `counter`?

Comment: This is the only idea for a fully client-side approach that I conjure. You could always spin up a node process in about 20 lines of code to monitor the path, count records, enforce the max, etc.

Comment: Yea if the `$id` wants to break away from that pattern I think that's what I'll have to do.

Comment: @Kato Something like root.child('somePath').numChildren() would be a great addition to the security structure assuming it could be fast. I'm working on an app where the # of things the user is allowed to have depends on how much they've paid. I'm handling it in some protected server side code - but now I've got security/validation logic in a few spots vs keeping it centralized in the Firebase Security Rules area.

Comment: @Kato Coming back to this a bit later I'm wondering if `.numChildren()` ever made it into the security API or is in the works?

Comment: Getting children without loading all records is still a very non-trivial issue in distributed, real-time computing. There is a REST API call available (shallow=true) that achieves a similar result, but it still takes a small performance hit if there are millions of children in the path, and nothing available for the SDK.

Comment: Amazing answers as always @Kato. I was wondering if you could recommend an approach for having a max of 12 items in my path **.ref(`connections/${myUid}/connection`)**

Answer (score 4):

While I think there is still no available rule to do such thing, there is a sample cloud function available here that does that:

https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/limit-children

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo. This is a reall strict and powerfull solution. It is because one can put the logic and restrict his/her users to limits on client side , however with Cloud Functions it is so easy to catch anyone who tries to bypass the rules that you've provided on client side. Check it  out  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/