# numChildren in Firebase rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I have `/members/($chatId)/($userId)`
 firebase datas.
(chat room with some users)

How to prevent write new userid, if the count of users in chat more than any number (ex. 6)? Of course, how to do it using firebase security rules. If you write solution in firebase bolt is more awesome ;)
Thank you!

Comment: The security rules for the Firebase Database have no `count` operator. Kato described two workarounds for that a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22644202/limit-number-of-records-that-can-be-written-to-a-path-reference-other-paths-in

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for duplicate.