# How to limit number of read/write records using custom claims in Firebase realtime database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

In firebase realtime database our users have a custom claim called **premium** this claim can have three values **LEVEL_1** , **LEVEL_2** or **REGULAR**
my database rules are:

```
    {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.token.admin === true",
    ".write": "auth.token.admin === true",
    "$uid": {
         ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
         ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
           "Boxes":{
            "Manual":{
             ".read": "auth.token.premium === 'REGULAR'",
             ".write": "auth.token.premium === 'REGULAR'",
           } 
           }
       },
  }
}
```

But I want to say if premium value is **REGULAR** only allow read/write for 5 records and if it is **LEVEL_1** only 20 records and for **LEVEL_2** access to all records and if we change from LEVEL_1 to REGULAR for example the rules do not remove records and just don't allow write more and allow for read 5 records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot going on in your use-case, so I'm going to address the **read** side first. As far as I can see, you have the following requirements:

1. `REGULAR` users can read up to `5` items.
2. `LEVEL_1` users can read up to `20` items.
3. `LEVEL_2` users can read all items.

You can secure this with a combination of queries, and a check on the queries in your security rules. Starting with the query, you apparently want these three queries:

```js
ref.orderByKey().limitToFirst(5)  // REGULAR
ref.orderByKey().limitToFirst(20) // LEVEL_1
ref.orderByKey()                  // LEVEL_2
```

The exact field/key you order on may not make a difference, but you must order on something as otherwise malicious users can still read more items than they're allowed to by simply ordering on different properties.

Now we can write the rules to allow these queries, and thus disallow other read operations:

```js
"items": {
  ".read": "query.orderByKey && (
            (auth.token.premium === 'REGULAR' && query.limitToFirst <= 5) ||
            (auth.token.premium === 'LEVEL_1' && query.limitToFirst <= 20) ||
            (auth.token.premium === 'LEVEL_2'"
}
```

---

For **write** operations: as Doug said, you can't use the number of nodes in security rules. This means you'll have to limit the number by either storing that count, having named slots, or some other workaround. Kato has written an example of this a few years ago, which shows a basic approach: [Limit number of records that can be written to a path (reference other paths in security rules)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22644202/limit-number-of-records-that-can-be-written-to-a-path-reference-other-paths-in)

Comment: Thanks Frank this is working for now, but I should consider simplifying it later

Answer (score 0):

Security rules don't have the ability to count anything.  They can't limit the number of times data may be read or written.

The alternative is to use a backend you control, and create an endpoint that performs the counting.  The endpoint will have to determine how to count the number of allowed read and writes.

Comment: Thanks, I already made a backend API but it's for the web app, the problem is in the mobile app they used firebase codes directly in the app and not using backend API so is it the right way if I get the custom claims from userIdToken and set limits inside the mobile app? also this way the limit only works in the mobile app and if someone get data using firebase functions they can have access to all records without limit

Comment: Also I think we can limit number of records: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data                                in this example they limited number of messages to last ten minutes