# Firebase Realtime Database Rules - Limiting child write operations

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am working on a project where I need to limit the answers to a specific post. I am trying to create a rule where the `write` tag allows or not the operation based in the amount of existing answers. The actual JSON looks like this:

```
"root": {
  "posts": {
     "$post_id": {
       // all other post stuff here
       answers: { // <== this is the path that i must allow or not the write operation based on the child node count
        "$userId_thatAnswered": { //user object here }
       }
     }
  }
}
```

does anyone know how I could perform this security?

Comment: Kato answered something like this a while ago. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22644202/limit-number-of-records-that-can-be-written-to-a-path-reference-other-paths-in

Answer (score 1):

There are no child counts available in Firebase security rules.  If you need to use a child count, you have to keep track of that value yourself, and put it in your database, so that you can reference it in your rules.